# Getting the total number of 'post' objects for a facebook user

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the total number of post objects that a user has associated with his or her account on Facebook.  Using Python, I can page through the posts like so:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token.token)

try:

    feed = graph.get_connections('me', 'feed')
    for item in feed['data']:
        celery_process_facebook_item.apply_async(args=[user_id, item, full_iteration])
    if full_iteration and feed['paging']['next']:
        next = feed['paging']['next']
        parsed = urlparse.urlparse(next)
        until = int(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['until'][0])
        celery_process_feed.apply_async(args=[user_id, provider, post_type, full_iteration, until])
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me the total number of posts in their feed afaict.  Is there a way to get that information?  I'd like to provide my customers with a progress bar showing we've processed x% of their items for them, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, here is the specific code I used to count up the posts:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token.token)
connection_type = 'feed'
total_posts = 0
try:
    feed = graph.get_connections('me', connection_type, limit=1000)
    while 'paging' in feed and 'next' in feed['paging'] and feed['paging']['next']:
        total_posts += len(feed['data'])
        print 'celery_count_facebook_posts @ %s total_posts' % (total_posts,)
        nextUrl = feed['paging']['next']
        parsed = urlparse.urlparse(nextUrl)
        until = int(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['until'][0])
        feed = graph.get_connections('me', connection_type, limit=1000, until=until)
    total_posts += len(feed['data'])
    print 'celery_count_facebook_posts FINISHED @ %s total_posts' % (total_posts,)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the number of posts directly as the returned data is paginated. You will have to resort to the indirect way i.e. get the feeds first time, check the next url and get the feed from the next url. Keep on doing thing untill next url is not there.